# How to maintain multiple variations of a github repo

Tags: laravel, wordpress, git, git-fork

I have a Laravel based API backend that will be provided to multiple clients on their dedicated servers(VPS) serving their independent users through mobile apps and SPA. Since the backend API will be identical for all clients I am using "Git pull" from the main repo to the client's servers to update the application. The image below may help in understanding my current structure.

[image]

However, clients will also need their unique websites(Landing page, contact us, etc) with some common features (mainly to show data from server to front end) that interact with the same DB the Laravel API is using.

How can I structure the code to solve this? I have a couple of ideas but am not sure if they are suitable.

1. Fork the Main Laravel API repo for each client and make the views on each forked repo for the clients individually. I think this might be efficient in terms of resource usage as it will be contained in one codebase. However, it may also create too many Repos that are all but identical for the front-end pages. Also, I feel this would cause too many issues when updating the rest of the code in the forked repos, Git pull, rebase, merge, etc might become too complicated(mission-critical) to ensure code integrity.
2. Make entirely new Laravel projects for the websites only and hook them up to the same DB as the API. Simple, no code duplication, and so issues when updating the Laravel API. However, I think this may become resource-intensive and is not a very efficient solution. I may be wrong about this so, please comment if you think otherwise.
3. Set up the websites independently, maybe even using WordPress(can be done very quickly, and would save me tons of development time). On a separate server(VPS) and make it communicate with the Laravel API project using some API. Maybe I could even set this up on the same server, would appreciate it if someone can comment if this is feasible(On the same server/VPS as the Laravel API).
4. I am open to suggestions.

I apologize if this is a silly question,  I am an independent developer who is still learning and not very knowledgeable about how to achieve this kind of distribution. I appreciate any input on this, especially how to structure it to be small-team friendly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per the given scenarios, I can give you some suggestions:

1. Create a sperate git branch for every client. By doing this you can deploy the client's branch on the server which contains requirements as per their specification.
2. You can create a client setup on database for yourself and write conditions for the unique requirements if the client is using the system.
   For Eg: You have three clients, you setup the clients as CLIENT001, CLIENT002 and CLIENT003. You can specify the conditions if the client_id=="CLIENT001" then deploy specific line of code.